# Compare a DateTime to the current date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, date

I am trying to use a condition on events when the start_at DateTime is equal to or greater than Today's date. 
I want to list upcoming events, but clearly they are not upcoming if they have already passed.

I have:

```
@appointments = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['move_id = ? AND start_at = ?', @move.id, Date.today])
```

I think I may be comparing apples and oranges here. It doesn't throw and error, just doesn't do what it is supposed to.

Help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it doesn't do what it's supposed to, what does it do?

Comment: Sorry poor explanation. It pulls in the events according to the association to move that it has but doesn't seem to acknowledge the condition on start_at. It pulls in the Date information but doesn't compare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
@appointments = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['move_id = ? AND start_at >= ?', @move.id, DateTime.now])
```

*Weird is that I can't find DateTime#now documentation.*

I'm using Postgres for this test.

```
>> Event.last.created_at.class
=> Time
>> Event.find(:first, :conditions => ['created_at >= ?', DateTime.now]).valid?
=> true
```

Migration field code

```
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
```

Comment: Thanks, I did actually try that too and while it pulls the DateTime for now it doesn't seem to perform comparing the two?

Comment: What's that start_at column type ?

Comment: start_at column is a DateTime

Answer (score 0):

as you said, start_at is equal or greater than today's date, perhaps it was a problem with the operator that was checking your event's start_at with today's date

```
Evento.find(:all, :conditions => ['start_at >= ?', DateTime.now])
```

if you're using mysql you could use "start_at >= CURRENT_DATETIME" or something like this also